# How to remove front and end character of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

For this input : `|PS  D#W ||OOOP #||# || QQWQ|`

I want to remove first and last pipe from the string by modifying below regex which I have written for any space and special char removal.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z|]","");
```

Also I want to combine this regex - `str.replaceAll("\\|+","|")` (For updating many pipelines in between string to one pipe). Is it possible to combine this to one regex?

Expected output: `PSDW|OOOP|QQWQ`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the desired output/result you want from the given input string.

Answer (score 2):

I won't ask why you want regex to remove first and last pipe (you could check if string starts and ends with pipe and use substring)
Remember that regex is heavier than working with strings.

But...to remove first and last you can use

```
str.replaceAll("^\\|(.*)\\|$","$1")
```

Explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/p9FEnU/1)

then the others.
Ofcourse it depends how long is string and how often you use this method - but it's shortest answer for so asked question.

Comment: Well, you need to escape the backslashes. Second, you could rewrite the replacement as `str.replaceAll("^\\||\\|$", "")`.

Comment: Right ofcourse - this is JAVA :)  Thank you - I've edited, If I use your regex than match is in 65 steps, with mine it's 10 steps. If you don't care performance it's ok to use any.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that using an alternation (`|`) would be fairly heavy for the regex engine.